# Can someone please explain .map() in laymans terms?

Tags: jquery

**UPDATE 1:**

Here is more of the script:

```
$(".favorites").sortable(
    {update:function() {

    var that = this;

    var urls = ""; 
    var texts = "";

    $.map($(".favorites a"), function(elt) { 
        urls += "url=" + elt.href + "&";
        texts += "text=" + $(elt).html() + "&"; 
    }); 

    $.ajax({
        url: 'favorites.asmx/save',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { strItems:$(that).sortable("serialize",{key:'item'}), strURLs:urls.substr(0,urls.length - 1), strTexts:texts.substr(0,texts.length - 1) },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    console.log(xhr.responseText); 
        },
        success: function() {
            console.log("Values sent:- strURLs: " + urls.substr(0,urls.length - 1));
        }
    });
```

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I have the following script which works, but I don't understand it:

```
$.map($(".favorites a"), function(elt) { 
    urls += "url=" + elt.href + "&";
    texts += "text=" + $(elt).html() + "&"; 
});
```

I understand the basic examples in this link: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/, but I don't understand the script I have posted above.

Comment: This looks like a misuse of `$.map()` to me; I think they want `$.each()` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The purpose of `map` is to create an array by taking each of the elements of the array or object you pass into it and filtering them through the function you give it; the function's return values are collected together into the resulting array, which is the return value of `map`.

That code isn't doing that. It's not returning anything from the iterator, and it's not using the resultant array. Basically it's just re-invented [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) by abusing `map`. That script should be:

```
$(".favorites a").each(function() { 
    urls += "url=" + this.href + "&";
    texts += "text=" + $(this).html() + "&"; 
});
```

(Note that I'm assuming here that `urls` and `texts` *have* been declared and initialized prior to the code you quoted.)

Here's an example of a correct use of `map`:

```
var hrefs = $.map($(".favorites a"), function(elt) {
    return elt.href;
});
// hrefs is now an array containing the `href`s of all of the links
```

Comment: I wonder if the author of the code used `$.map` in order to enjoy a more standard ordering of the parameters. That's the only reason I could think of to do that.

Comment: I've added more of the script to the original question.

Comment: @oshirowanen: I figured they were initialized somewhere. :-) The answer is still the same, the code isn't using `map` as it's intended to be used, could be (arguably should be) using `each` the way I've shown above.

Comment: `each` does make a lot more logical sense in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the $.map iterates through an existing array, passes it to the callback you provide ("function", above), then it takes those new items that were returned from your callback and puts them into a brand-spanking-new array.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have is taking all the links (`<a>` tags) from container with class called "favorites" and build two strings: one is the target URL's of the links and the second is the text "inside" each link.

From the looks of it, those two strings are then sent to the server.

As T.J. Crowder perfectly explained, you don't have to use `.map()` at all, the fact it's working does not mean it's correct or best practice.

Comment: I've added more of the script to the original question.

Comment: OK, so like I said - the code is sending those values to web service called `favorites.asmx` to web method called "Save" which probably save the data (URL's and text of the links) to database. Any further question?

Answer (score 0):

`map()` turns an array into another array by using the function passed to it on each element of the source array:

```
var source = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ];

var result = $.map(source, function(element){
    return element.toString() + " Rocks!";
});

// result now contains [ '1 Rocks!', '2 Rocks!', '3 Rocks!', '4 Rocks!' ]
```

In the use case you show, `map()` is actually the wrong method to call since there's no resulting array (the function doesn't return anything). This usage simply uses `map()` to iterate over the collection and do something unrelated with the elements.

In that case, you should really use `each()` to simply iterate over the source array and do something with each element.

Comment: This does not answer the question which is about specific script.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - It certainly does. Look at the last two sentences.

Comment: I've added more of the script to the original question.

Comment: @oshirowanen - That is still a mis-use of the map() function. each() should be used instead.